# Scala parallel collections workload balancing strategies

Tags: multithreading, scala

I've been toying around with the Scala parallel collections and I was wondering if there was a way to easily define what workload balancing strategy to use.

For instance, let's say we're calculating how many prime numbers we have between 1 and K = 500 000:

```
def isPrime(k: Int) = (2 to k/2).forall(k % _ != 0)
Array.range(1, 500*1000).par.filter(isPrime).length
```

If all `.par` is doing is dividing the data to be processed in different contiguous blocks, then there's not much advantage in parallelizing this algorithm, as the last blocks would dominate the total running time anyway.

On the other hand, running this algorithm such that each thread has an equally distributed share of work would solve the issue (by having each one of `N` threads start at index `x € (0 .. N-1)` and then work only on elements at `x+kN`).

I would like to avoid having to write such boilerplate code. Is there some parameter that would allow me to easily tell Scala's library how to do this?

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/configuration.html

Comment: Afair the Scala collections work with job-stealing by default, without any parameters.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin that's orthogonal to my question.